# Convert array of objects with nested elements into separate object list in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

Problem Statement: We are faced with the task of processing an array of complex objects, where each object contains nested sub-objects. Our goal is to unravel this structure and create a new array that consists of individual elements from these nested structures. This transformation is necessary to simplify data processing and enable more efficient analysis and manipulation of the data.

**Input.json**

```json
{
  "link": [],
  "record": 1,
  "pageSize": 10,
  "matchedEntities": [
    {
      "busEntity": {
        "ContactView": {
          "idObject": "6940205       ",
          "ApplicationId": "CNT01",
          "clnsdNm": "Jhon cena",
          "certifiedContact": {
            "id": "2",
            "CertifiedContactDesc": "Uncertified"
          },
          "PtPostalAdd": {
            "item": [
              {
                "id": "3149850       ",
                "label": " Postal Address",
                "mainAddrCd": {
                  "id": "3             ",
                  "label": "Lookup Postal Address Type",
                  "addrTypDesc": "Primary",
                  "addrTyp": "P"
                },
                "mdmOpsAddrInd": {
                  "rowidObject": "2",
                  "label": "Lookup Postal Address Type",
                  "addrTypDesc": "Not Appliacble",
                  "addrTyp": "N"
                },
                "PostalAddress_rowidObject": "3209850",
                "PostalAddress": {
                  "rowidObject": "237",
                  "srcAddrln1": "BERNARDELLI",
                  "srcCity": "PORTO",
                  "srcState": "RJ",
                  "srcPstlCd": "5600re",
                  "srcCountryCd": {
                    "rowidObject": "32            ",
                    "label": "Lookup Source Country",
                    "cntryCd": "BR",
                    "cntryDesc": "Brazil"
                  },
                  "addrLn1": "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI",
                  "city": "PORTO REAL",
                  "state": "RJ",
                  "pstlCd": "27570000",
                  "countryCd": {
                    "cntryDesc": "Brazil",
                    "cntryCd": "BR"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "43",
                "label": " Postal Address 2",
                "mainAddrCd": {
                  "id": "3             ",
                  "label": "Lookup Postal Address Type",
                  "addrTypDesc": "Primary",
                  "addrTyp": "P"
                },
                "mdmOpsAddrInd": {
                  "addrTypDesc": "Not Appliacble",
                  "addrTyp": "N"
                },
                "PostalAddress_id": "23",
                "PostalAddress": {
                  "srcAddrln1": "test",
                  "srcCity": "test",
                  "srcState": "test",
                  "srcPstlCd": "5600re",
                  "srcCountryCd": {
                    "rowidObject": "32            ",
                    "label": "Lookup Source Country",
                    "cntryCd": "BR",
                    "cntryDesc": "Brazil"
                  },
                  "addrLn1": "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI",
                  "city": "PORTO REAL",
                  "state": "RJ",
                  "pstlCd": "27570000",
                  "countryCd": {
                    "cntryDesc": "Brazil",
                    "cntryCd": "BR"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "matchRule": "MRS Contact Search Match|1",
      "matchScore": "100"
    },
    {
      "busEntity": {
        "ContactView": {
          "id": "6940205       ",
          "ApplicationId": "CNT02",
          "clnsdNm": "Alexis Vieira",
          "certifiedContact": {
            "CertifiedContactDesc": "Uncertified"
          },
          "PtPostalAdd": {
            "item": [
              {
                "id": "3149850       ",
                "label": " Postal Address",
                "mainAddrCd": {
                  "id": "3             ",
                  "label": "Lookup Postal Address Type",
                  "addrTypDesc": "Primary",
                  "addrTyp": "P"
                },
                "mdmOpsAddrInd": {
                  "addrTypDesc": "Not Appliacble",
                  "addrTyp": "N"
                },
                "PostalAddress_rowidObject": "3209850",
                "PostalAddress": {
                  "srcAddrln1": "BERNARDELLI",
                  "srcCity": "PORTO",
                  "srcState": "RJ",
                  "srcPstlCd": "5600re",
                  "srcCountryCd": {
                    "rowidObject": "32            ",
                    "label": "Lookup Source Country",
                    "cntryCd": "BR",
                    "cntryDesc": "Brazil"
                  },
                  "addrLn1": "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI",
                  "city": "PORTO REAL",
                  "state": "RJ",
                  "pstlCd": "27570000",
                  "countryCd": {
                    "cntryDesc": "Brazil",
                    "cntryCd": "BR"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "facet": []
}
```

***Actual output:***

```json
{
  "partyContact" : {
    "cntId" : [ "CNT01", "CNT02" ],
    "cntName" : [ "Jhon cena", "Alexis Vieira" ],
    "certifiedContact" : [ "Uncertified", "Uncertified" ]
  },
  "postalAddress" : [ {
    "mainAddrCd" : [ "Primary", "Primary" ],
    "addressType" : [ "Not Appliacble", "Not Appliacble" ],
    "srcAddrLn1" : [ "BERNARDELLI", "BERNARDELLI" ],
    "srcCity" : [ "PORTO", "PORTO" ],
    "srcState" : [ "RJ", "RJ" ],
    "srcPstlCd" : [ "5600re", "5600re" ],
    "addressLine1" : [ "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI", "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI" ],
    "city" : [ "PORTO REAL", "PORTO REAL" ],
    "state" : [ "RJ", "RJ" ],
    "postal_Code" : [ "27570000", "27570000" ],
    "srcCountryCd" : [ "BR", "BR" ]
  }, {
    "mainAddrCd" : "Primary",
    "addressType" : "Not Appliacble",
    "srcAddrLn1" : "test",
    "srcCity" : "test",
    "srcState" : "test",
    "srcPstlCd" : "5600re",
    "addressLine1" : "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI",
    "city" : "PORTO REAL",
    "state" : "RJ",
    "postal_Code" : "27570000",
    "srcCountryCd" : "BR"
  } ]
}
```

***Jolt spec used***

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "matchedEntities": {
        "*": {
          "busEntity": {
            "ContactView": {
              "ApplicationId": "partyContact.cntId",
              "clnsdNm": "partyContact.cntName",
              "certifiedContact": {
                "CertifiedContactDesc": "partyContact.certifiedContact"
              },
              "PartyAlternateId": {
                "item": {
                  "*": {
                    "altIdType": {
                      "idTyp": {
                        "0002": {
                          "@(3,altIdVal)": "partyContact.partyUid"
                        },
                        "0008": {
                          "@(3,altIdVal)": "partyContact.metalPortalUserId"
                        },
                        "0011": {
                          "@(3,altIdVal)": "partyContact.ecpPortalUserId"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "PtPostalAdd": {
                "item": {
                  "*": {
                    "mainAddrCd": {
                      "addrTypDesc": "postalAddress[&2].mainAddrCd"
                    },
                    "mdmOpsAddrInd": {
                      "addrTypDesc": "postalAddress[&2].addressType"
                    },
                    "PostalAddress": {
                      "srcAddrln1": "postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn1",
                      "srcAddrln2": "postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn2",
                      "srcAddrln3": "postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn3",
                      "SrcAddrln4": "postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn4",
                      "srcCity": "postalAddress[&2].srcCity",
                      "srcState": "postalAddress[&2].srcState",
                      "srcPstlCd": "postalAddress[&2].srcPstlCd",
                      "srcSystem": "postalAddress[&2][&2].srcSystem",
                      "srcDoNotStd": "postalAddress[&2].srcDoNotStd",
                      "addrId": "postalAddress[&2].addressId",
                      "addrLn1": "postalAddress[&2].addressLine1",
                      "addrLn2": "postalAddress[&2].addressLine2",
                      "addrLn3": "postalAddress[&2].addressLine3",
                      "addrLn4": "postalAddress[&2].adddressLine4",
                      "city": "postalAddress[&2].city",
                      "county": "postalAddress[&2].county",
                      "state": "postalAddress[&2].state",
                      "pstlCd": "postalAddress[&2].postal_Code",
                      "countryCd": {
                        "cntryCd": "postalAddress[&3].srcCountryCd"
                      },
                      "vldtnStsCd": "postalAddress[&2].validation_Status_Code",
                      "enrchdInd": "postalAddress[&2].enrichedIndicator"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

***Expected output***

```json
[
  {
    "partyContact": {
      "cntId": "CNT01",
      "cntName": "Alexis Vieira",
      "certifiedContact": "Uncertified",
      "partyUid": "980",
      "postalAddress": [
        {
          "mainAddrCd": "Primary",
          "addressType": "Not Appliacble",
          "srcAddrLn1": "test",
          "srcCity": "test",
          "srcState": "test",
          "srcPstlCd": "5600re",
          "addressLine1": "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI",
          "city": "PORTO REAL",
          "state": "RJ",
          "postal_Code": "27570000",
          "srcCountryCd": "BR"
        },
        {
          "mainAddrCd": "Primary",
          "addressType": "Not Appliacble",
          "srcAddrLn1": "test",
          "srcCity": "test",
          "srcState": "test",
          "srcPstlCd": "5600re",
          "addressLine1": "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI",
          "city": "PORTO REAL",
          "state": "RJ",
          "postal_Code": "27570000",
          "srcCountryCd": "BR"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "partyContact": {
      "cntId": "CNT02",
      "cntName": "Alexis Vieira",
      "certifiedContact": "Uncertified",
      "partyUid": "980",
      "postalAddress": [
        {
          "mainAddrCd": "Primary",
          "addressType": "Not Appliacble",
          "srcAddrLn1": "test",
          "srcCity": "test",
          "srcState": "test",
          "srcPstlCd": "5600re",
          "addressLine1": "2000 RUA FERNANDO BERNARDELLI",
          "city": "PORTO REAL",
          "state": "RJ",
          "postal_Code": "27570000",
          "srcCountryCd": "BR"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More identifiers to representate index nodes such as

`[&3].partyContact` or `[&4].partyContact`

and

`[&7].partyContact` or `[&8].partyContact.` should be added as in the following case :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "matchedEntities": {
        "*": {
          "busEntity": {
            "ContactView": {
              "ApplicationId": "[&3].partyContact.cntId",
              "clnsdNm": "[&3].partyContact.cntName",
              "certifiedContact": {
                "CertifiedContactDesc": "[&4].partyContact.certifiedContact"
              },
              "PtPostalAdd": {
                "item": {
                  "*": {
                    "mainAddrCd": {
                      "addrTypDesc": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].mainAddrCd"
                    },
                    "mdmOpsAddrInd": {
                      "addrTypDesc": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].addressType"
                    },
                    "PostalAddress": {
                      "srcAddrln1": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn1",
                      "srcAddrln2": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn2",
                      "srcAddrln3": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn3",
                      "SrcAddrln4": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcAddrLn4",
                      "srcCity": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcCity",
                      "srcState": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcState",
                      "srcPstlCd": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcPstlCd",
                      "srcSystem": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2][&2].srcSystem",
                      "srcDoNotStd": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].srcDoNotStd",
                      "addrId": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].addressId",
                      "addrLn1": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].addressLine1",
                      "addrLn2": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].addressLine2",
                      "addrLn3": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].addressLine3",
                      "addrLn4": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].adddressLine4",
                      "city": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].city",
                      "county": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].county",
                      "state": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].state",
                      "pstlCd": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].postal_Code",
                      "countryCd": {
                        "cntryCd": "[&8].partyContact.postalAddress[&3].srcCountryCd"
                      },
                      "vldtnStsCd": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].validation_Status_Code",
                      "enrchdInd": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].enrichedIndicator"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but note that there's no such node called `"PartyAlternateId"` unlike to the currently stated one, so part is removed.

Comment: Can you please explain me the below ? why it is having an issue to access

if i want to access "id" from the "PtPostalAdd" object array items. 

"PtPostalAdd": {
                "item": {
                  "*": {
"id": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&].id",
}
}

Comment: Hi @barbaros  How can I extract the "id" from the "item" array within the "PtPostalAdd" object in my input data and assign it new id value as one of the parameters among, such as "mainAddrCd," "addressType," or "srcAddrLn1"? The Jolt specification I provided, "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].id," does not seem to be working.

Comment: @RakeshGR levels matter. If it's needed to put followed by `"PtPostalAdd": { "item": { "*": {` you can use `"id": "[&6].partyContact.postalAddress[&1].id_1";`otherwise if that should be nested within the `"mainAddrCd"` object, then use `"id": "[&7].partyContact.postalAddress[&2].id_2"`